# How can I use SSO to login to my Ubuntu machine instead of Local User Management

Tags: ubuntu-one, users, single-sign-on

Instead of maintaining local user accounts, I would like to be able to use Ubuntu SSO (Ubuntu One) accounts to authenticate the logins to my Ubuntu machine.

Any chance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The topic was [mooted](http://summit.ubuntu.com/uds-p/meeting/19622/desktop-p-sign-in-with-u1-credentials/) at the Ubuntu Developer Summit in late 2011. OMG! Ubuntu! [covered the topic](http://omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/11/logging-into-ubuntu-using-ubuntu-one/).

The Ubuntu One team liked the idea, but there are many technical challenges before logging in with SSO credentials will be possible. Don't expect to see it anytime soon.

Comment: any update on this?